# How to make Bootstrap as browser's default rendering style

Tags: css, browser, twitter-bootstrap-3, default

Since browser has its own default cascading style sheet applied to webpage, is there a way to replace it with Bootstrap? Like whether there is a browser that support this or one has to look into open source browser's source code and replace some parts with Bootstrap.

Comment: It wouldn't work because Bootstrap requires the proper classes and such in the HTML in order to work. Most sites already have their own style sheets that override the browser's defaults, and the sites that don't have CSS won't have the necessary class attributes and HTML structure to make Bootstrap work.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are looking to do. Any set of CSS rules, including those of bootstrap, override the user agent stylesheet. What are you trying to do that cannot be done by just bringing in Bootstrap on top of the default styles?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. But why all on earth wanna do that? I think you need decompiled source of the browser to do this.

Comment: Paula, you probably figured this out, but try position: relative; for your caption css section. You removed your question so I'm guessing you solved it somehow.

Comment: Yes. With position relative works. I solve it anyway. Thanks ^_^